# How do I find subnets on the network in order to scan them for hosts?

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

I'm new to Security and I'm doing INE's Penetration Testing Student Learning path. In the current lab, (Find the Secret Server) we have this setup:

[image]

The exercise focuses on adding an entry to the routing table. However, I wonder if we didn't have that image as information how I could find all the networks by myself?

I used `nmap` to scan the exact 192.168.222.199 IP address but I have no idea how I would go about discovering 192.168.222.0/24

Comment: What is the exact nmap command you used? That would provide some more context about what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Hint: using **traceroute** to find the network devices being traversed at layer 3. What you need to figure out is what kind of **IP address ranges** (RFC1918) are in use in that network. Once you have that information, then you have a **scope**. For example, for a 192.168.x.x network you are going to scan /24. Then you'll discover some hosts.

Comment: @kate it looks like they scanned the specific IP because they already had the map. The question is how to proceed without a map. The question is how to discover the network ranges ...

Comment: @MiguelP in your question, would you know the existence of the company and test web servers?

Comment: @Spyros I would say so, yes

Answer (score 3):

*In the answer below it is assumed that the scanning machine is located in one of the company's internal networks (concluded by its IP address)*

The problem in locating the secret server is that each host is in a different network. It is a problem because you don't know which networks to scan in order to locate your targets.

A thing that could help you is to examine the [routing table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) of the scanning machine (assuming it is configured as a legit machine of the network). It may reveal valuable information on the networks actually used by the company (making your scans more targeted).

If you don't have that, you have to go blindly. A naive (but guaranteed) solution is to try and scan ([ping sweep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_sweep)) all private networks and see what comes up.

A better approach is to utilize your knowledge of the web servers' existence. Since you know that the company's web server is located at `176.16.88.81` and the test one is at `192.168.241.12`, you could scan the `176.16.88.0/24` and `192.168.241.0/24` networks, thus avoiding `10.0.0.0/8` and saving time.

If that wouldn't result in anything useful (which, in this case, would not), you could widen your searches (i.e. scan the `176.16.0.0/16` and `192.168.0.0/16` networks) until you get something you can work with.

At the end of the day, you can scan as wide a network as you like (even the whole internet). The only problem with really wide network searches is resource consumption and, of course, time.

**EDIT**:

For completeness, I'm including @[schroeder](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6253/schroeder)'s ideas (see his comment):

You can also sniff the network in order to reveal interesting network access patterns (e.g. hosts on the same network as the scanning machine may access the other networks and/or the secret server). Also, you can seize control of the company's router and take a look at the routing configuration, which will reveal all the networks of the company.

Comment: or sniffing traffic to look for evidence of subnets, or cracking the router and looking at the configuration

Comment: @schroeder good points. I focused on the scanning part for some reason.